# Flow: How do I type-annotate a local/global variable?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

If I have the process.browser variable in my code how can I annotate it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can declare the `process` variable:

```js
// @flow

declare var process: { browser: number }

const foo = process.browser * 3
```

Here is a sample of it in action: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAmBTAxtAhgJzaAG56gAOusGaAztQFygDeoARhfNWrgwHYCuAWxZdQAX2QZYPagBdQkWLFABeMhSq0AdGwSdcoAFSgAzIiA

In this example the global variable is declared locally in the file that consumes it, however it might be more ideal to declare this globally via a library definition. Going this route, it will automatically be defined for every file.

For example, add the following to `<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed/process.js` and you should be set. You may need to restart the Flow server.

```js
declare var process: { browser: number }
```

Comment: Is there a way to declare variables like this in legacy projects too? Using vanilla JS and a separate declarations file, perhaps?

Comment: Hm adding a file in `flow-typed/misc.flow.js` seems to work, as answer says. :)